# Delay in notifications

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange, notifications

For the second time, i saw what i think to be a bug in superuser(i don't know if it doesn't happens in other SE sites).

I can see the title of the page where i am with a "(n)"(by n, i mean a number). It should mean that there is a notification. But when im going to check there is no notification.

The notification takes about a minute to reach the "Stack Exchange" button, after reaches the tab title.

Is this the normal behaviour, or it shouldn't happen?
(This time, it was just a badge)

Comment: At least on the front page, number indicates the number of questions updated since the page was loaded. Click *1 question with new activity* to load the updated questions and reset the title.

Comment: @DanielBeck But it just disapperared when the "badge" notification was seen. Can it be related?
I think that no question was updated when i saw this.

Comment: True, both inbox and updated questions apparently contribute towards the number in the title.

Comment: But then, why did the notification took so "long" to appear when the warn was already issued in the title bar?

Comment: In fact, now (when i received 1+ in this question), i received one priviledge, and the message that this post was updated ("(2)" in the title bar), but it had absolutely no delay.
Could the "supposed bug", be just related to any kind of maintenance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well... this seems to be stupid(and it is). It is related with the new questions that keep appearing when the page is not refreshed.

> "One question with new activity"

The badge notification, only was loaded when the page was refreshed, and that explains why did it not appear (That minute was spent reading question titles before refreshing).